# In stim's `CORRELATED_ERROR` docs example, where does the 60% come from?

Tags: error-correction, stim

[image]

I do not see what exactly adds up to 60%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probabilities are 1/5, 1/4, and 1/3. The chance of none of them firing is (4/5) * (3/4) * (2/3) = 2/5 = 40%. This leaves a 60% chance that one of them fires.